# Why use GTM/datalayer over regular GA events?

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

**Background**

- I am a product manager for an SPA (Single Page App). We've
  implemented GTM + datalayer to send data to GA.
- My question is that it is not clear to me why we've been advised
  by a GA data consultant to use various datalayer push events to send
  data to GA.
- We are using Enhanced Ecommerce for recording product impressions &
  clicks etc, which makes more sense as the EE reporting requires more
  data. But for simpler/regular events, it doesn't make sense to me.
  Can someone help me understand?

**Example**

The following example datalayer push is for when someone logs in:

```
dataLayer.​push​({
'event'​:​ 'logIn', 'action'​:​ 'logged in', 'label'​:​ 'old user', 'userID'​:​ 
'65659897', 'email'​:​ 'test@test.com'
});
```

I am not clear on why should we use this over a 'regular' GA event, e.g

```
Category: Navigation
Action: Login
Label: <userID>
```

In many ways, the Category/Action/Label format is easier for us to understand. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to come down to a matter of conventions. Inside GTM the values from the datalayer will be mapped to category/action/label in any case, so you'd have to ask the consultant why he thinks his naming scheme is better (e.g. since the values can be used in tags other than GA maybe he thinks a more "abstract" naming scheme is more appropriate).

As far as the programming aspect is concerned the values could just as well be renamed to match the GA event tracking conventions.

Comment: Thanks - we will be asking, but wanted to check beforehand in case there was something obvious, perhaps around EE reporting etc

Comment: My best guess is that your consultant is re-using the "event" key (which is necessary for GTM to work) as the GA event category to save a few characters in the datalayer.